# Change Position of a <a> element with a <img> inside

Tags: javascript

I am running into a problem in my application where I am trying to use an range slider to determine the position of a link containing an image. Basically it grabs the value of the ranges and uses it to determine the position. However, that does not happen. Instead it does absolutely nothing. Any thoughts on why this might occur?

JS Code:

```
//Social Media
var rangeX = document.getElementById("rangeX");
var rangeY = document.getElementById("rangeY");

var socialChooser = document.getElementById("socialsChooser");
var inputInvite = document.getElementById("inputInvite");
var submitsocialMedia = document.getElementById("submitSocial");
var Discord = document.getElementById("discord");
var YouTube = document.getElementById("youtube");

submitsocialMedia.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var socialContainer = document.getElementById("socialsContainer");

  if ( socialChooser.value === "discord") {
    const a = document.getElementById("discordJoin");
    if (a.children.length === 0) {
      const linkText = document.createElement("img");
      linkText.id = "linkText";
      console.log(linkText.id);
      linkText.src = "/html/imgs/Discord-Logo-White.png";
      a.style.marginLeft = rangeX.value + "px";
      a.style.marginTop = rangeY.value + "px";
      a.appendChild(linkText);
      a.title = "Discord Invite Link";
     a.href = `${inputInvite.value}`;
    }
  }
```

HTML Code:

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="1000" value="500" id="rangeX"> X
<input type="range" min="1" max="1000" value="500" id="rangeY"> Y
```

Comment: Your code has a few conditions that must be met before it attempts to use the values of the ranges, e.g. `if ( socialChooser.value === "discord")` and `if (a.children.length === 0)`. Are those conditions true?

Comment: Maybe ignore manipulating the anchor children (src, id, etc.) from the code. IMHO you can set <a> position anyway. Focus on styling, set conditions to true

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to test your code. So many elements referenced but not available. Instead, here's a mockup of a working range slider/element added to DOM combo. Maybe it will help you discover what's not working in your setup.

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div');
let rangeX = document.getElementById("rangeX");
let rangeY = document.getElementById("rangeY");
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  div.innerHTML += `<a href='#' style='margin-left:${rangeX.value}px; margin-top:${rangeY.value}px;'>The link</a>`;
});
```

```css
div a {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="500" value="10" id="rangeX"> X
<input type="range" min="1" max="500" value="10" id="rangeY"> Y
<button>create</button>
<div>

</div>
```